# Change URI of main page after app was opened by a custom URI

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I use custom URIs to open my app on Windows Phone 8. When the device receives a URI with my custom protocol a custom UriMapper extracts the parameters and returns a URI of the form `/MainPage.xaml?param1=test`. This opens the main page which in turn uses the parameters to do something.

The problem: If the app is being opened with a custom URI, the custom URI stays in the back-stack. If I then open a sub page and navigate back with the back button the main page gets loaded with the parameters, which results in the app processing the parameters again. I want to replace the URI in the back-stack with a parameter-less version once the parameters have been processed.

Comment: If you could specify the programming language that you are using to do something with the parameters, we might be able to answer your question better. If it is javascript, you can use `window.location.replace("main-page-url-without-parameters")` after you are done processing the parameters.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find a parameter you could remove the current page (with navigation from the stack) and navigate again to the same page like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("param1"))
    {
        string param = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["param1"]; //Get "Param" this QueryString. 

        // .. Do Stuff

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();

    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.